# Using two lan eth0,eth1 by ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, local-area-network

I have a ubuntu server. I need to use eth0,eth1 by connecting two LAN cable. I edit network interface by `vi /etc/network/interface`.
eth0 works fine but eth1 dose not work.
What is my problem?

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 292.16.1.201
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.1.1.0
    broadcast 10.1.1.255
    gateway 292.16.1.16
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-search quran.medu.ir
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 42.1.1.201
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    getway 42.1.1.16
```

Comment: Why are the network and broadcast lines inconsistent with the other information on eth0?

Comment: Please mark correct answers to your previous questions. At least some of them seem to have reasonable answers.

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of eth1 you have a bad word: `getway`.

And BTW: You can use only one default gateway per system, then I advice to you delete whole line with `getway`.